# looking for an example of how to WRITE a masterdetail file

Tags: filehelpers

I would like to see a simple example of WRITING a MasterDetail file using FileHelpers.

I understand how to READ a MasterDetail file, however, I can not find an example of creating one.

Comment: Did you have any luck?  I too ran into this problem today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish it this way.

```
    var engine = new MasterDetailEngine<MyHeader,MyDetail>(); 
    var listMasterDetail = new List<MasterDetails<MyHeader,MyDetail>>();

    var a = new MasterDetails<MyHeader, MyDetail>();
    a.Master = headerData;
    a.Details = listDetail.ToArray();
    listMasterDetail.Add(a);

    engine.WriteFile(@"C:/SomeFolder/MyFile.txt", listMasterDetail);
```

Comment: Thanks... I'll look at your suggestion later.

At this point, I may use create the file manually.  I've used FileHelpers for reading files (with Master / Detail records) ... for creating the file with Master / Detail records there does not seem to be any examples, so I thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion..

I'm wondering if you could clarify your code a bit for me?  Could you expand on the listDetail line?

How did you setup / define listDetail  (in the "a.Details = listDetail.ToArray();" line)

Again, thank you.

Comment: @JDA -- I figured out how you are doing this -- thanks for the information it was just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding dummy data to John Doe's code in order to quickly test

```
var headerData =
    new Customers
    {
        Address = "address",
        City = "City",
        CompanyName = "CompanyName",
        ContactName = "ContactName",
        ContactTitle = "ContactTitle",
        Country = "Country",
        CustomerID = "CustomerID"
    };

var listDetail =
    new Orders[]
    {
        new Orders
        {
            CustomerID = "CustomerID",
            EmployeeID = 1,
            Freight = 1.03M,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            OrderID = 1234,
            RequiredDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
            ShippedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
            ShipVia = 1
        },
        new Orders
        {
            CustomerID = "CustomerID",
            EmployeeID = 1,
            Freight = 4.57M,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            OrderID = 5678,
            RequiredDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
            ShippedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
            ShipVia = 1
        }
    };

var engine = new MasterDetailEngine<Customers, Orders>();
var listMasterDetail = new List<MasterDetails<Customers, Orders>>();

var a = new MasterDetails<Customers, Orders>
{
    Master = headerData,
    Details = listDetail.ToArray()
};
listMasterDetail.Add(a);

engine.WriteFile(@"C:/temp/MyFile.txt", listMasterDetail);
```